# are we supposed to commit the android and ios folders after doing expo prepublish?

Tags: expo

I just ran expo prepublish and it generated a .gitignore and ios/ and android/ folders.  Am I supposed to commit the ios/ and android/ folders because it wasn't explicitly excluded by the .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the ios/android folder unless you've made some changes in it.